# Does the variable store the datatype itself

Tags: c, windows, variables, types, ram

I am learning programming language. I wonder if each variable is treated differently based on the data type, how does the processor identify it if in memory all variables are stored in bits (bytes). Is the variable's data type stored in memory for the variable in question?

I have searched it but i cant find the same topic as my quesion

Comment: If we are talking about C as tagged, then no, the type isn't stored anywhere (in the final executable). It is the compiler who knows the type and is generating instructions appropriate for working with this type to generate the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about C as tagged, then no, the type isn't stored anywhere (in the final executable). It is the compiler who knows the type and is generating instructions appropriate for working with this type to generate the desired result.